# Change TSQL script to DAX(PowerBi)

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

may I ask you for help? I have this data where I need to find how many 7s are in the row.

If there is number ,,7,, in column ,,Counting,, 10-19 times in the row so write it text ,,green,,

If there is number ,,7,, in column ,,Counting,, 20-29 times in the row so write it text ,,blue,,

If there is number ,,7,, in column ,,Counting,, 30-52 times in the row so write it text ,,red,,

> Number    Week    Counting
>
> 1380  1   5
>
> 1380  2   5
>
> 1380  3   5
>
> 1380  4   7
>
> 1380  5   7
>
> 1380  6   7
>
> 1380  7   7
>
> 1380  8   7
>
> 1380  9   7
>
> 1380  10  7
>
> 1380  11  7
>
> 1380  12  7
>
> 1380  13  7
>
> 1380  14  7
>
> 1380  15  7
>
> 1380  16  4
>
> 1380  17  6
>
> 1380  18  3
>
> 1380  19  3
>
> 1380  20  4
>
> 1380  21  6
>
> 1380  22  6
>
> 1380  23  6
>
> 1380  24  5
>
> 1380  25  5
>
> 1380  26  6
>
> 1380  27  4
>
> 1380  28  4
>
> 1380  29  5
>
> 1381  1   1
>
> 1381  2   5
>
> 1381  3   5
>
> 1381  4   6
>
> 1381  5   5
>
> 1381  6   6
>
> 1381  7   6
>
> 1381  8   6
>
> 1381  9   4
>
> 1381  10  5
>
> 1381  11  5
>
> 1381  12  6
>
> 1381  13  5
>
> 1381  14  7
>
> 1381  15  3
>
> 1381  16  4
>
> 1381  17  6
>
> 1381  18  7
>
> 1381  19  6
>
> 1381  20  5
>
> 1381  21  7
>
> 1381  22  6
>
> 1381  23  4
>
> 1381  24  5
>
> 1381  25  4
>
> 1381  26  5
>
> 1381  27  3
>
> 1381  28  4
>
> 1381  29  4

I created TSQL script what works but I need to change that script to DAX(PowerBi)
Thank you!!!

```
with test as (
    select Number,Week,Counting,row_number() over (order by (select null)) as rn
    FROM [vf_test_03] as t
),
LG as (
SELECT rn,Number, Counting, CASE WHEN Counting <> LAG(Counting) OVER(order by rn) THEN 1 ELSe 0 END lg
FROM test
), 
SU as (
SELECT rn,Number,Counting, SUM(lg) OVER(order by rn) su
FROM LG
),
test02 as (
SELECT Number,Counting, COUNT(*) as countt
FROM SU
GROUP BY Number, Counting,su
),
umisteni as (
select te.Number,te.Counting,te.countt,
    case when countt between 10 and 19 then 'green' 
         when countt between 20 and 29 then 'blue'
         when countt between 30 and 50 then 'red'
    end as Liga
from test02 as te
where Counting = 7
)
select Liga, Number
from umisteni
where Liga is not null
group by Liga,Number
order by Number
```

Comment: Your sample data is not that clear to me. Can you provide sample data in a better way?

Comment: I am not sure how can I send you for example EXCEL file... Because I am at work and it is not possible to send you example of data in other way....